# Deleting comments under posts in the mod queue should be easier

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderator-tools, deleted-comments, moderator-queue

Ever since mods gained the ability to undelete comments, deleting them has become easier as the confirmation dialog was removed.

However, this is not the case in the mod queue — I still get a confirmation dialog for each comment I want to delete in the queue under a custom-flagged post (single-comment flags can be deleted just fine). And since this is the place from where I delete comments the most, it can be annoying.

In addition, the "purge comments" button, when invoked from the queue, refreshes it, so I have to scroll back down, remember which post I just purged, and mark the flag as helpful. Usually not a big issue but if there are multiple "obsolete comments" flags, then it can get confusing.

Could the workflow for comment thread moderation from within the queue be improved? Ideally, make comment deletion work like everywhere else on the site, and make the purge button AJAX-based like the comment deletes.

Comment: I don't get this in the Stack Overflow mod queue. Which URL are you visiting where you see this?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker This is about comment threads under custom-flagged posts. I'll clarify.

Comment: This happens in the close-vote review queue, too.  I will often clean up comments before closing something, and normally have to goto the question itself to make the process go quicker.